# Дешифрация файлов на сервере (java, spring)

Tags: java, файлы, spring, шифрование, aes

**Дано:**

Приложение, которое хранит зашифрованные файлы на сервере (если абстрагироваться, то любое облако типа DropBox, GoogleDrive т.д. только с *шифрованием* файлов на хранилище). Юзеры работаю по WEB. (вводят https://example.com и т.д.). Сервер использует java Spring (MVC).

**Описываю проблему**(абстрактно)**:**

1. Прилетает МультипартФайл c POST от юзера на сервер. Сервер его принимает -> переводит в байты -> шифрует -> сохранят на HDD.
2. Дальше идет запрос от пользователя («покажи файлы»). Сервер берет зашифрованный файл(ы) -> дешифрует -> отдает юзеру.

**Проблема:** При дешифрации мне нужно создать дешифрованный(е) файл(ы) на диске, а только после этого отдавать юзеру. Но как этого не делать ( не создавать File decrFile = new File(“****”)? *(иначе смысл шифрации файлов пропадает вовсе)*

Наверняка уже есть какое-то решение данной проблемы, но в силу нехватки опыта столкнулся с проблемой.

Comment: А прямо так обязательно задейтсвовать диск? Почему бы просто не расшифровать его в оперативной памяти и отослать сразу клиенту?

Comment: Используйте функцию темповых файлов и по закрытии стрима удаляйте

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim  - Идея с ОП интересная. Я изначально так и хотел сделать, но столкнулся именно с проблемой "Как?". Но после обдумывания поселилась еще одна мысль - если, к примеру активных пользователей 100 (одновременно) и у каждого в "облаке" по 1Гб файлов.... ну Вы, я уверен, поняли к чему я виду :) Если вы знаете как реализовать через ОП и подскажите - буду безмерно благодарен.

Comment: @GenCloud - Через темповые файлы тоже можно. Но идея защищенности будет нивелирована этой реализацией (имхо). Если вы обладаете знаниями как это сделать "ювелирно" (защищено) и поделитесь со мной - буду безмерно благодарен.

Comment: Не думаю что злумышленник будет копать в темп-директории системы ибо "зачем", вы сгенерировали файл - отдали юзеру во вьюху - и тут же удалили, если конечно Вы так волнуетесь за безопасность - выставите права доступа на директорию, отдайте управление только системе. Что-то на подобии должно быть у Вас в контроллере File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".tmp"); ... /decrypt, write into temp/ model.addAttribute("file", temp); temp.delete();

Comment: @GenCloud Да, этот вариант можно реализовать. Но опять же на сервер (а именно на HDD) будет ложиться довольно большая часть бесполезной работы, и при большом трафике..хм..может произойти фиаско с быстродействием (хотя шифрование и быстродействие еще то сочетание). А как Вы считаете, если выдвинуть нагрузку по шифрованию на "морду" юзера? Вот, прочитал статью [ссылка](https://habr.com/post/130085/) - это довольно легко, но по поводу безопасности появляются нюансы

Comment: Никогда не отдавайте какую-либо работу клиенту, червато дырами. Самый оптимальный вариант тот который я Вам предложил- а проблемы с диском что-то даже не уверен что начнуться. А вообще я бы советовал Вам взлянуть в сторону кластера + Kafka

Comment: А все не так сложно. Загружаем файл, расшифровываем и в виде массива байт, отсылаем юзверю. Вот тут базовая инструкция, чтоб навести на путь истинный: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file